# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php

Olá, Tenho uma dúvida! Peguei um código PHP de Acesso a painel utilizando Usuário e senha para estudo. Em certo momento foi necessário a troca para mysqli_connect. Com esta troca fiz muitas mudanças no código. Uma dela foi transformar para mysqli_real_escape_string, onde ao tentar conectar ao painel aparece este erro:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /

Estudei a documentação do mysqli_real_escape_string e observei que é necessário colocar o parâmetro de conexão, que no meu caso é $conecta. O mesmo não funcionou.

Podem me auxiliar? Desta forma posso estudar em cima do meu erro: Segui parte do Código:

```
$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);
```

Grato pela ajuda Carlos Louvato

Comment: Sua hipótese que falta o parâmetro de conexão está certo. Provavelmente não funcionou porque fez outra coisa errado ou se equivocou na ordem dos mesmos. Tem como colocar na pergunta como fez?

Comment: $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conecta, $theValue) : mysql_escape_string($conecta, $theValue);

Comment: Erro seguinte: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /